# Simple HQL sentence could not execute query

Tags: c#, nhibernate, hql

I'm new with NHibernate with HQL, but I'm trying to execute a HQL sentence but I got the following error

```
An exception of type 'NHibernate.Exceptions.GenericADOException' occurred in NHibernate.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Could not execute query[SQL: SQL not available]
```

Can anyone help me to found where I did some mistake ?

**CODE**

```
var valoresAgregadosAnoAtual2 = _repositorio.GetReceitas2<ReceitaGeral>(
    "SELECT MONTH(p.DateHourDataCreation), SUM(p.Value) " +
    "FROM Receita p " +
    "WHERE YEAR(p.DateHourDataCreation) = YEAR(GETDATE()) " +
    "GROUP BY MONTH(p.DateHourDataCreation) " +
    "ORDER BY MONTH(p.DateHourDataCreation)");

public class ReceitaGeral
{
    [Required]
    public virtual int MonthNumber { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual double ValueMonth { get; set; }
}

public IEnumerable<T> GetReceitas2<T>(string sql)
{
    var context = new NHibernateHelper();
    var receitas = context.ConsultaHql<T>(sql);
    return receitas;
}

public IList<T> ConsultaHql<T>(string sqlQuery)
{
    ISession session = GetSession();
    IQuery query = session.CreateQuery(sqlQuery);
    return query.List<T>();
}
```

**Receita Class**

```
  public class Receita
  {
    [Required]
    public virtual int Receita_Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual DateTime DateHourDataCreation{ get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual Company CodeCompany { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual Source CodeSource { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual Service CodeService { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual Equipment CodeEquipment { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual Person CodeClientPerson { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual Person CodeSellerPerson { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual DateTime DateEmission { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual int Quantity { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual double Value { get; set; }
}
```

I ran the SQL Sentence generated by NHibernate and it works fine in SQL Server.

**UPDATE**

The image below show that the query return 2 values, I think it should return a reference to my class ReceitaGeral. How can I do it ?

If I put a HQL sentence like `FROM Receita` it return a reference to Receita class, and now I want a referece to ReceitaGeral

[image]

Comment: Is `ReceitaGeral` a mapped class or just a class you're using to return query results?

Comment: Just a class that I'm using to return query results. The mapped one is Receita.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there, just need *result transformer* and proper *ALIAS* for each column.

Alias *(see  `AS MonthNumber` and `AS ValueMonth`)*:

```
var valoresAgregadosAnoAtual2 = _repositorio.GetReceitas2<ReceitaGeral>(
    "SELECT MONTH(p.DateHourDataCreation) AS MonthNumber, SUM(p.Value) AS ValueMonth" +
    "FROM Receita p " +
    "WHERE YEAR(p.DateHourDataCreation) = YEAR(GETDATE()) " +
    "GROUP BY MONTH(p.DateHourDataCreation) " +
    "ORDER BY MONTH(p.DateHourDataCreation)");
```

Transformer *(using Alias will create instances of `ReceitaGeral`)*:

```
public IList<T> ConsultaHql<T>(string sqlQuery)
{
    ISession session = GetSession();
    IQuery query = session.CreateQuery(sqlQuery);
    return query
       .SetResultTransformer(Transformers.AliasToBean<T>()) // e.g. T is ReceitaGeral
       .List<T>();
}
```